# Resizing FontAwesome icons with FitText

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using FitText (http://fittextjs.com/) to resize some titles in my page.  I don't have any problem using it with h1, h2, etc but it does not work on the icons from FontAwesome.  I know it's possible to resize fontawesome icons with this pluggin but I just don't get why it is not working for me.
Here is what I tried so far :

**This works perfectly (regular text) :**

HTML :

```
<span id="title1">Text to resize</span>
```

CSS :

```
#title1{
    font-size: 72px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JS :

```
jQuery("#logo").fitText(1, { minFontSize: '20px', maxFontSize: '72px' })
```

**This does not work (FontAwesome) :**

HTML :

```
<span id="awesome-bolt" class="fa fa-bolt"></span>
```

CSS :

```
#awesome-bolt{
display: block;
width: 100%;
font-size: 250px;
```

}

JS :

```
jQuery("#awesome-bolt").fitText(1, { minFontSize: '100px', maxFontSize: '250px' })
```

Comment: If your looking to resize text based on viewport size, I might also recommend you look at using `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, and `vmax` to create viewport sized font. Browser support isn't great for it (especially ios), but it's pretty cool. Here's a link http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: use `jQuery("#awesome-bolt:before")` just a wild guess if it works

Comment: Looks cool but I need something that will work perfectly on ios and any mobile.. That's why I am trying to resize my icons with FitText.

Comment: @Durgesh Chaudhary - I just tried and it did not worked

Answer (score 0):

When you are using FitText at that time if the font-size is greater than  100px than you have to set the exact width as per your font-size.

Like in your case you have set 250px so use 250 percent width,

CSS :

```
#awesome-bolt {
    display: block;
    width: 250%;
    font-size: 250px;
}
.icn {
    width:100%; 
    overflow:hidden ; 
}
```

HTML : Also you have to set 100% width to parent div to avoid horizontal scroll bar

```
<div class="icn">
    <span id="awesome-bolt" class="fa fa-bolt"></span>
</div>
```

JS : Its same like you have used.

```
jQuery("#awesome-bolt").fitText(1, { minFontSize: '100px', maxFontSize: '250px' })
```